# Tagged images of bald and balding men

Tags: data-request, images, faces

Is there an image dataset of bald and balding men? Best would be classified/tagged images with labels like "bald", "not bald", "early balding", "etc".

Related links:

https://matthewbilyeu.com/blog/2019-03-21/the-boombox-incident

my source & comments: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19462007

similar question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/14060/1511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Category:Bald men](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Bald_men) on Wikimedia Commons, right now with 525 images.

Comment: cool! would be nice to link this to wikidata or human profile pictures

Comment: Structured Data on Commons is brand new, right now a search for Depicts:Baldness only yields 3 hits, but it will for sure change in the near future. https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?search=haswbstatement%3AP180%3DQ181391&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1&ns6=1&ns9=1&ns12=1&ns14=1&ns100=1&ns106=1

Comment: Is it possible to get URLs to the images (even if 3) with a Sparql query?

Comment: Not yet, but it is being built: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T141602

Answer (score 0):

It's not tagged, but one option would be to [run the above algorithm](https://matthewbilyeu.com/blog/2019-03-21/the-boombox-incident) on the NIST Mugshot dataset:

https://www.nist.gov/srd/nist-special-database-18

> The database consists of a total of 3248 images of variable size using PNG formatting with metadata TXT files corresponding to each per image.
>
> There are images of 1573 individuals (cases) 1495 male and 78 female.
>
> 3248 segmented 8-bit gray scale mugshot images (varying sizes) of 1573 individuals
>
> 1333 cases with both front and profile views (see statistics above)
>
> 131 cases with two or more front views and 89 cases with two or more profiles
>
> images scanned at 19.7 pixels per mm

The files have the naming structure like `00117_1_F.txt` for **F**orward facing and `00604_1_R.txt` for **R**ight facing. Total download is 1.7 GB zipped.

Also on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/kwisatzhaderach/nist-mugshots

[image]